# Mobile client authentication/authorization with API: .NET Maui/.NET Core external web API

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, maui

I’m new to android mobile application development in .NET Maui, and am trying to understand the authorization/authentication functionality for the mobile client and the web API. Work has asked me to build an android mobile application, being a .NET shop, my preference is using .NET Maui. I have found Auth0, API keys and JSON web tokens for authentication and for authorizing users, this is stored in our SQL Server DB.

Background for the mobile application, it will not be available publicly to download, just internal employees will be using it, the API will be available publicly but only communicating with the internal mobile app.

Questions:

1. From what I read, best practice is to secure the applications, you can use/add JWT, API keys or Auth0 to the .NET Core external web API, but do I need to add any of the above to the mobile application? I think my preference would be to use JWT or API keys. There is also TLS with certificates.
2. After the mobile apps first communication with the API, from my understanding based on what type of authentication you use, and let’s assume we will use JWT, an encrypted token will be sent back to the client, but upon calling the API subsequently (after being logged in successfully) as there will be additional GET, PUT and POST calls, do I need to capture the encrypted token from the first initial call, pass it back to the API somehow, or is this done automatically when there is a subsequent call to the API for that session, via a cookie or something else?
3. For data being transferred back and forth from the client mobile app. to the API and vice versa, the data needs to be encrypted, how is this done?

.NET Maui code behind – Login Content page

Button clicked event

//Control validation

```
//API call, this will return a list for the user, and there will be additional API’s calls to authenticate the user at the application level.
//Validate user name and password API
var adminUser = await _IAdminUserService.GetData(UserName.Text.Trim());

//Application logic


//Subsequent call to the API
How does the authentication with the API work at this point, and after successful user authentication?
```

```
Service class that calls the API

public async Task<List<User>> GetData(string User)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl + "GetData/" + User, string.Empty));

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _User = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<User>>(content, _serializerOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            _User = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return _User;
}
```

```
//API Controller

[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet("GetData/{Name}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(User))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetData(string Name)
{
    var _User = await _IAdminUserService.GetData(Name);
    if (!_User.Any())
        return NotFound("No record");
    return _User;
}
```

I do have this working on my local machine

I’ve also read that you need to apply the [AllowAnonomous] attribute for the first initial call(s), and then use the [Authorize] attribute (after users are authenticated at the application level).

Looking at so many different video’s, links, etc., I am on brain overload, and it is possible that I am misunderstanding something, so hopefully some of my questions can be answered.

Thank you for all your help,

William

Comment: You'll get better responses if you [edit] your question to be more focused.  You're asking multiple questions at once which makes it difficult to concisely respond to.  Generally, if you're using a token based system, every request will need to include the token.  If you want to encrypt the data, the easiest is just to use a SSL connection, otherwise you will need to handle that on your own.